# Can use SSIS without SQL Server or Azure Data Factory Licensing?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, azure-data-factory

I like SSIS, I already created packages but I don't have SQL Server license.
Can I run the package and get scheduler in server?

Answer (score 1):

Nope.

You have a developer license which is quite clear what constitutes development (development tasks only - you touch prod, you're engaged in production work)

Using hacks to run devenv.exe and launch packages are clear intent to circumvent licensing. Carefully copying assemblies and patching a box to support "bad" actions is even more egregious license violation.

What happens when your organization is audited by Microsoft? There's the "oh, we noticed these license violations. Let's get those fixed, please. Maybe you should buy some azure credit to offset the penalty." Harm determined, minor penance required.

Then there's "Oh, you were malicious about breaking the rules. We have more lawyers and accountants than you can imagine." Harm determined and hell is coming with us.

It's not you that will be hauled to court, it's your organization and you can bankrupt them (if you use Enterprise Edition parts that can be a hefty bill).

You either pay for what you use or spend your time rolling your own implementation. Some of it's not hard (copy data from one table to another). Others are far more devilish.

Integrating [David Browne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7297700/david-browne-microsoft)'s excellent comment on pricing for SSIS in ADF vs VM

> Prices for SSIS in Azure Data Factory start from under 0.60USD/hour.  And you can start/stop the SSIS runtime from an ADF pipeline. Pricing for SQL Server Standard Edition on an Azure VM is similar.

- https://azure.microsoft.com/pricing/details/data-factory/ssis
- https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-factory/how-to-schedule-azure-ssis-integration-runtime
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator

Comment: So can you give me suggestion which one the cost efficient between using on prem sql business intelligence or Azure Data Factory SSIS integration ? because the process is not much, only 1 per day

Comment: Prices for SSIS in Azure Data Factory start from under 0.60USD/hour. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-factory/ssis/   And you can start/stop the SSIS runtime from an ADF pipeline. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/how-to-schedule-azure-ssis-integration-runtime.  Pricing for SQL Server Standard Edition on an Azure VM is similar. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/